# How Can I Reference Environment Variables in serverless.ts?

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless

I'm using serverless-ssm-fetch in my serverless.ts file, which resolves many of the variables that are environment specific.  This works great when I'm referencing these variables in my code, however, I have two values in my serverless.ts file itself that I'd like to draw from SSM Parameter Store.  Below is my serverless.ts file, and what I'm trying to do to pull in lambda-security-group-ids and lambda-subnet-ids is working, but I'm not sure how to reference them within the serverless.ts file.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';
import importFacility from '@functions/ImportFacility';
import ProcessEvent from '@functions/ProcessEvent';

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
    service: 'myservice',
    frameworkVersion: '2',
    custom: {
        webpack: {
            webpackConfig: './webpack.config.js',
            includeModules: true,
        },
        bundle: {
            ignorePackages: ['pg-native']
        },
        serverlessSsmFetch: {
            DB_Host: 'database-host~true',
            PORT: 'serverless-database-port~true',
            DB_NAME: 'clinical-database-name~true',
            DB_USER_NAME: 'database-username~true',
            DB_PASSWORD: 'database-password~true',
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY: 'serverless-access-key-id~true',
            AWS_SECRECT_KEY: 'serverless-access-key-secret~true',
            LAMBDA_SECURITY_GROUP_IDS: 'lambda-security-group-ids~true', // WANT TO REFERENCE
            LAMBDA_SUBNET_IDS: 'lambda-subnet-ids~true' // WANT TO REFERENCE
        }
    },
    plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-ssm-fetch'],
    provider: {
        name: 'aws',
        runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
        apiGateway: {
            minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
            shouldStartNameWithService: true,
        },
        environment: {
            AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1'
        },
        lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221',
        vpc: {
            securityGroupIds: [`${process.env.LAMBDA_SECURITY_GROUP_IDS}`], // NOT WORKING
            subnetIds: [`${process.env.LAMBDA_SUBNET_IDS}`] // NOT WORKING
        }
    },
    functions: { importFacility, ProcessEvent },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

Comment: does `'${self:custom.serverlessSsmFetch.LAMBDA_SECURITY_GROUP_IDS}'` work

Comment: that did work, I was making it overly complicated when trying to find the right syntax.

Comment: Maybe you can add what worked for you as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering juste had the issue

the syntax :

```
vpc: {
  securityGroupIds: ['${ssm:${self:custom.serverlessSsmFetch.LAMBDA_SECURITY_GROUP_IDS}}'], 
  subnetIds: ['${ssm:${self:custom.serverlessSsmFetch.LAMBDA_SUBNET_IDS}}]
}
```

worked for me.

As far as I understand you have to use the syntax as it would have been rendered while using serverless.yml template